# tcpdump: "packet exceeded snapshot"

Tags: tcpdump, packet, capture, pcap

I am using tcpdump to look into some pcap files, but in the output, I see the following error, instead of getting the header information:

```
packet exceeded snapshot
```

I googled it, but I couldn't find any detailed explanation about the meaning of this error and what can be the reason for getting it.

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164140/tcpdump-wont-capture-entire-packet but NOT the same.

Comment: Is it the same error mentioned on that link?That's actually my question, does this error means that because of the limitation in the size of the captured snapshot, tcpdump cannot retrive the packet?

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the source code at
[tcpdump-dicom print-lwapp.c](https://github.com/malaterre/tcpdump-dicom/blob/master/print-lwapp.c),
this message is issued when the size of the captured data is not enough to contain
the entire header of the message.

The
[Manpage of TCPDUMP](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html)
says for the `-s` parameter:

> **--snapshot-length=snaplen**
>
> Snarf snaplen bytes of data from each packet rather than the
>   **default of 262144 bytes**.

Snapshot refers to the captured data, and package means an entire transmitted
message.

It seems that this is not the fault of tcpdump but that of the software
that created the pcap files, dumping a too-small part of the packets.
But if the packets are complete, then tcpdump has a problem with the format of
the dump.